# How do I have to understand the question: " How did insurance compensate for the losses attached to those pandemics? "

Tags: meaning, questions

I have to answer a few questions about pandemics like:

> What was their impact in terms of casualties and what was the profile on the economy of the countries that were hit?
> How did insurance compensate for the losses attached to those pandemics?

How do I have to understand the second question? Are we talking about insurance losses or country losses?

PS: The questions were asked by a non native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just examine part of the sentence, "How did insurance compensate for the losses?" It is clear insurance compensates for the loss. Could it compensate itself? It only makes sense if it is compensating another party. Perhaps you should explore the meaning of *compensate*.